# comparing a known object in different pictures to find position and orientation error?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, positioning, computer-vision

I am new to this place. I am doing a project where i use X ray images with known object dimensions. During my scan i want to compare the images with respect to first image to measure the position and orientation errors during my manipulator movement.

1) I use a known object next to my measuring object to check the errors.
How can i compare two or different images with same known objects?

2) I am planning to use matlab toolbox for the further processing. Is it possible to do in matlab? If so can somebody help

3) Is it possible to use POSIT algorithm to just find these errors?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you mean, please post more info regarding your object and images. In what sense are they different? (rotation, shear, translation, other type of aberration, or is it just signal difference...). Usually, when you want to compare something to something else you can use convolution or correlation (or xcorr2, conv2). If you could post a sample image, maybe it'll be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a fairly complex question, without adding a lot of detail. We can only help you properly if you provide a bit more context, perhaps some examples of images.

By the sound of it: you should use the [image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/image/).

If you have multiple images of test objects with known objects beside it, it is easiest to use `normxcorr2` and friends (see [this page](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/demos/image/cross_correlation/imreg.html) for a worked-out example).

If you have a large amount of pictures of the same scene, possibly with rotations, scaling, optical distortions, etc. from image to image, and you still want a sub-pixel accurate estimation of your object's position, perhaps [image registration](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/images/f20-9579.html) is the better way to go.

But again: you should provide more detail. Only then can we give you a better, less generic answer.